# Error in changing database to getWritableDatabase() method

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, nullpointerexception, getwritabledatabase

I have source code that use the database.
My database codes are in a class and when I insert anything from this class there is no problem.
But if the method call in the other class the error message " java.lang.nullpointerexception " will be shown from this line `SQLiteDatabase sd = getWritableDatabase();`

This is my main class :

```
public static class SchemaHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
         private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "adv_data.db";
         // TOGGLE THIS NUMBER FOR UPDATING TABLES AND DATABASE
         private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
         SchemaHelper(Context context) {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
         }

         @Override
         public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            // CREATE JOINT TABLE
             db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE"+ JointTable.TABLE_NAME  
            + "("+ JointTable.ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"         
            + JointTable.NAME +" TEXT, "
            + JointTable.FAMILY + " TEXT,"
            + JointTable.ADDRESS+"TEXT,"
            + JointTable.PARTICIPATIONNUM +"Text,"
            + JointTable.RECOGNITIONNUM + "TEXT,"
            + JointTable.USAGE +"TEXT );");


         }
         @Override
         public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
             int newVersion) {
             Log.w("LOG_TAG", "Upgrading database from version "
             + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
             // KILL PREVIOUS TABLES IF UPGRADED
             db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ JointTable.TABLE_NAME);

             // CREATE NEW INSTANCE OF SCHEMA
             onCreate(db);
                        } // End of onUpdate class
```

=============================== INSERT To Table ===================================

```
         public  long addJoit(String name, String family, String address,
                 String participationNum ,String recognitionNum, String usage ){

             ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
             cv.put(JointTable.NAME, name);
             cv.put(JointTable.FAMILY, family);
             cv.put(JointTable.ADDRESS, address);
             cv.put(JointTable.PARTICIPATIONNUM, participationNum);
             cv.put(JointTable.RECOGNITIONNUM,recognitionNum);
             cv.put(JointTable.USAGE, usage);

             SQLiteDatabase sd = this.getWritableDatabase();// this line get the error
             long result= sd.insert(JointTable.TABLE_NAME,
                     JointTable.NAME, cv);
             return result;
         }





             }
}
```

this is the other class that call the method

```
MainActivity.SchemaHelper sh = new MainActivity.SchemaHelper(null);

long result=  sh.addJoit("name", "family", "address", "participationNum", "recognitionNum", "usage");
```

I want to know the reason 
thank's

Comment: You miss a space here: `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE"+ JointTable.TABLE_NAME` it should be `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ JointTable.TABLE_NAME` or the table won't be created at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem has solved by calling the method in this way :

```
MainActivity.SchemaHelper sh = new MainActivity.SchemaHelper(getBaseContext());
```

The constructor need `getBaseContext()` method.

Thanks to all of you to helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems  that `sh` is null because you pass null in `SchemaHelper` constructor,So change

```
MainActivity.SchemaHelper sh = new MainActivity.SchemaHelper(null);
```

to

```
SchemaHelper sh = new SchemaHelper(MainActivity.this);
```

And also add space in your create table statment,.i.e. Change

```
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE"+ JointTable.TABLE_NAME  
            + "("+ JointTable.ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"         
            + JointTable.NAME +" TEXT, "
            + JointTable.FAMILY + " TEXT,"
            + JointTable.ADDRESS+"TEXT,"
            + JointTable.PARTICIPATIONNUM +"Text,"
            + JointTable.RECOGNITIONNUM + "TEXT,"
            + JointTable.USAGE +"TEXT );");
```

to

```
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ JointTable.TABLE_NAME  
            + "("+ JointTable.ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"         
            + JointTable.NAME + " TEXT, "
            + JointTable.FAMILY + " TEXT,"
            + JointTable.ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
            + JointTable.PARTICIPATIONNUM +" TEXT,"
            + JointTable.RECOGNITIONNUM + " TEXT,"
            + JointTable.USAGE + " TEXT);");
```

And also set `context` properly ,i.e. change

```
 SchemaHelper(Context context) {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
         }
```

to

```
 Context mContext;
 SchemaHelper(Context context) {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
         mContext = context;
         }
```

and change

```
 SQLiteDatabase sd = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

to

```
 SQLiteDatabase sd = mContext.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: I changed it but still there is a problem. It work , but when it called from the other class the message will shown

Comment: I do that but it's the same.

Comment: @Khodayar see edited answer.And also try to clear project and also delete existing app after change.

Comment: try like this, SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

Answer (score 0):

Make the different class for simplicity.

```
 public class Insert {

    private Context context;
    private SchemaHelper schemaHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;


    public Insert(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public  long addJoit(String name, String family, String address,
                         String participationNum ,String recognitionNum, String usage ){

        schemaHelper=new SchemaHelper(context);
        database=schemaHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
        cv.put(JointTable.NAME, name);
        cv.put(JointTable.FAMILY, family);
        cv.put(JointTable.ADDRESS, address);
        cv.put(JointTable.PARTICIPATIONNUM, participationNum);
        cv.put(JointTable.RECOGNITIONNUM,recognitionNum);
        cv.put(JointTable.USAGE, usage);


        long result= database.insert(JointTable.TABLE_NAME,
                null, cv);
        database.close();
        return result;
    }

}
```

In MainActivtity class,

```
Insert insert=new Insert(MainActivity.this);


  long add=insert.addJoit("name", "family", "address", "participationNum", "recognitionNum",        "usage");
```

Also if Table is not created, add spaces in  sql statement. ie

```
db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE "+ JointTable.TABLE_NAME  
        + " ( "+ JointTable.ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "         
        + JointTable.NAME + " TEXT, "
        + JointTable.FAMILY + " TEXT, "
        + JointTable.ADDRESS + " TEXT, "
        + JointTable.PARTICIPATIONNUM +" TEXT, "
        + JointTable.RECOGNITIONNUM + " TEXT, "
        + JointTable.USAGE + " TEXT ); ");
```

Comment: There is a error in this line " database=schemaHelper.getWritableDatabase();  "